# Is it Sunnah to light up agarbatti (perfumed incense sticks) after someone dies?

Tags: sunnah, muslim-practices

In South India, Muslims light up [agarbathi](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Incense_of_India) after someone dies. Is it a Islamic practice?

[image: Incense being sold in an Indian market in Bangalore (Image source: Wikipedia)]

Comment: a better question would be "if it's not sunnah, is it allowed?"

Answer (score 1):

Not Sunnah. Just pray for him and follow the funerals-according-to-the-quran-and-sunnah

http://sunnahonline.com/library/fiqh-and-sunnah/276-funerals-according-to-the-quran-and-sunnah